# How to connect a digital meter between alternator and batteries?

Tags: voltage, current, generator, alternator, meter

We are using a 24 V, 100 A external alternator in our vehicle to charge leisure batteries. We need to monitor the alternator’s voltages and current on a digital meter but the alternator is grounded with vehicle’s body and vehicle also has an external system grounded with its body, so the alternator current is divided between system and leisure batteries.

I just wanted to ask how I can connect a digital meter between the alternator and the leisure batteries so I can see on my digital meter the total voltage and current from the alternator.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to monitor - the alternator output or the battery current? You seem to say both.

Comment: Use a hall effect current clamp

Comment: Is the 24 V alternator for the leisure batteries only, or is it the vehicle's main alternator, charging both leisure and start batteries?

Comment: @Finbarr alternator output current.

Comment: @PeterBennett 24v external alternator for leisure batteries only. It is not vehicle's main alternator.

Comment: If the 24V alternator is for leisure batteries only, and the vehicle alternator is for the vehicle battery only, the alternator current will not be divided between the leisure and vehicle batteries even if they share a common ground.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how, using a 100 V DC - 100 A, dual digital panel meter with an operating voltage of 4.5 - 30 V DC and a matching 100 A shunt.

[image]